# NUL character in an ASCII-Based protocol over UART

Tags: c, serial, uart, embedded

I am developing a UART protocol based on ASCII encoding. Communication is between a PC and an STM32 board. Packet format is like this:
Packet: {STX,DATA,ETX} Where STX and ETX are `0x02` and `Ox03` in ASCII.
Example:

**STX**HELLO**ETX** in Hex would be: **0x02** 0x48 0x45 0x4c 0x4c 0x4f **0x03**

My question is where exactly is the position of `\0` character in my packet? is it after ETX like this: **STX**HELLO**ETX**\0 or after HELLO like this: **STX**HELLO\0**ETX** ?

Comment: It's your protocol, you get to choose. Do you even need the `\0` if you end always with `ETX`?

Comment: Nulls are rarely used in line protocols, in effect ETX is filling the role in your protocol that a null serves when a program internally stores a null-terminated string.  Packet buffers usually track length, rather than using a terminating null, but even if they use a terminating null it is removed on sending and added on receiving.

Answer (score 7):

You specify your packet format as {STX,DATA,ETX}.

The entire DATA content of the packet is contained within the DATA field, between the STX and ETX.

If you decide to send NUL-terminated strings in your packets then the NUL is part of the string - part of your DATA field.

So you would send:  **STX**HELLO\0**ETX**

Comment: I would say that the NUL terminator of a C string is a feature of the C language and should not be considered as part of the string.  The actual string to be sent would just be the characters up to, but not including, the NUL.

Comment: Indeed, this response is very incorrect, and appears to have confused the asker into mistakenly accepting it.  The format originally described simply does not send a null, and indeed **most line protocols do not use nulls**.  If at some point a packet with or without the framing STX/ETX is **stored inside a computer** in a null terminated C string rather than in a length-designated buffer, then a null would be added.  But it's not necessarily the case that this will happen at all.  Typically you would only see null-terminated strings when constructing or deconstructing packet fields.

Comment: @PeterBennett, OPs question states "I am developing a UART protocol". It's OPs choice how strings are sent, as others note.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on the DATA (the 'HELLO' word in your example):

--if it's a null-terminated string (a C-string), in wich a string is represented by an array of chars ended by a null character '\0',

or:

--if it's a 'normal' array of characters.

so the packet can be:

--**STX**HELLO\0**ETX** for the null-terminated char array: [**0x02** 0x48 0x45 0x4c 0x4c 0x4f **0x00** **0x03**]

or:

--**STX**HELLO**ETX** for the normal char array: [**0x02** 0x48 0x45 0x4c 0x4c 0x4f **0x03**]

or:

--the null char can be anywhere in the packet!...it's your protocol, as colin-s commented;

Comment: While this includes the overwhelmingly usual possibility, you've buried it in the middle, and failed to really explain *why* that is the usual.

Comment: @chris-stratton: i haven't any intention to 'explain why that is the usual' possibility... i only mentionned 'some' possibilities since the question is a bit general...